# Trying to add TipTap WYSIWYG to Vue form text area

Tags: vue.js, tiptap

I am attempting to add tiptap (https://github.com/scrumpy/tiptap) to a form textarea field.

I can't get this to work. I get no errors, but the form element does not display.

Here is the component:

```
<template>
  ...

          <div class="field">
            <label>Body</label>
            <editor-content :editor="editor" />
          </div>

        ...
<script>
...
import { Editor, EditorContent } from 'tiptap'
...
  components: {
    Notification,
    EditorContent
  },
  data () {
    return {
      ...
      editor: null
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.editor = new Editor({
      content: '<textarea name="piece_body" v-model="piece_body" rows="20" placeholder="Start composing here..."></textarea>'
    })
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    this.editor.destroy()
  },

</script
```

>

Comment: Add yout code please

Comment: trying to SO is rejecting it as too much code.

Comment: maybe a codepen or codesandbox?

Comment: using quill for now which worked in 5 minutes.